# AngularJS Sends OPTIONS request instead of POST

Tags: angularjs, post, amazon-s3, httprequest

I'm trying to upload a picture to my S3 bucket. I'm using AngularJS v1.2.13. 
When I use the simple case as displayed in their docs (submit form with `action` tag) everything works fine. However, if I want to do it the Angular way with `ng-click` Angular sends an `OPTIONS` request instead of a `POST` request.

The following is the Service code, it first goes to the server to get a signature (I know that part is fine) then tries to POST with everything.

```
myServices.factory('s3', function($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.upload = function(fileName) {

        return $http(
            {
                method:"POST",
                url: "sign",
                data: { "fileName": fileName }
            }
        ).then(
            function(result) {
                // success
                //resolve the promise as the data
                var data = result.data;
                var url = "https://" + data.bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com/";

                return $http.post(url, {
                    "key": data.key,
                    "AWSAccessKeyId": data.awsKey,
                    "acl": data.acl,
                    "policy": data.policy,
                    "signature": data.signature,
                    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
                    "success_action_redirect": "http://localhost:3000/s3Uploaded"
            }).then(
            function(response) {
                // success
                console.log("s3.upload, success: ");
                console.log(response);
            },
            function(response) { 
                // failed
                console.log("s3.Upload, fail: ");
                console.log(response);
            }
        );

    },
        function(response) { 
            // failed
            console.log("s3.sign, fail: ");
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
};

return service;
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's due to the CORS policy and is done by the browser automatically, nothing wrong there.

Comment: You are missing to configure the cors policies in your s3 bucket, to allow the domain your are using.

Comment: [Teena Pamecha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7364271) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289282) saying "Maybe you did not Configure CORS for an Amazon S3 Bucket or enable core origin [Configure CORS for an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cors.html) [How Do I Configure CORS on My Bucket?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors)"

Answer (score 1):

Angular is sending a preflight request, so if you can go back to your first plan, do that!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44343635/1308736

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22968724/1308736

Answer (score 0):

In S3 headers in CORS add header:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 0):

Server will check either you should be allow to post some data on server itself or  not as per the

*cross origin resource sharing policy*

that is quite normal that you are getting options request.
your ApI server should have configured to allow request from your domain to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need add a  new CORS Policy configuration into own AWS S3 bucket

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cors.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://example.org</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```