# Call symfony 2 rest api with Angular JS, cors

Tags: angularjs, api, symfony, cross-domain, cors

I'm using angularJS to call a restfull API in symfony 2.

My angularJS app url is `angular.me.dev`
My symfony2 api url is `api.me.dev`

I followed [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/tjamps/11d617a4b318d65ca583) to make my restfull api.

The problem is when I try to call this api

```
$http.({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.me.dev/api/articles',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
})
```

An error occured: (here on google chrome):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.me.dev/api/articles. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

(and on on firefox):

```
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

what did I find about this ?

- [AngularJS Sends OPTIONS request instead of POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346408/angularjs-sends-options-request-instead-of-post)
- [AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)

Then I decide to allow headers, origin, ... on my server like this:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

No change

I add to AngularJS

```
#coffee script
app.config ['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider) ->
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']
]
```

Then I decided to install NelmioCorsBundle in my symfony api but I didn't see any change.

Finally, I notice a call works

```
$http.({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.me.dev/api/articles',
})
```

Here the call return a 401 response (good, i need to be logged)

```
$http.({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.me.dev/public/api/users',
})
```

Here I have a call doesn't need authorization, it works.
I found only when I remove headers it works, and when I had any headers (content-type or authorization for example) an error occured.

Can anyone help me ? thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, my bad.

I said NelmioCors seems not working but i did something wrong.

I try again with nelmio cors bundle, using this configuration.

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/':
            allow_origin: ['http://angular.me.dev']
            allow_headers: ['Authorization', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Origin', 'X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
```

It's working !
NelmioCorsBundle resolve the problem.

https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle