# Angular CORS simple request triggers preflight with Authorization header in POST

Tags: angular, cors, authorization, preflight

The preflight is not supposed to happen for simple requests as per the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

This is indeed the case if I don't put the additional "Authorization" header in the request:

```
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Authorization": "Basic _base64_string_"
```

Without "Authorization" header:

```
:authority:www.target.com
:method:POST //<----------------This is correct
:path:/oauth2/access_token?client_id=xxx-xxx
:scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
content-length:79
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded//<----------------This is correct
origin:http://source.com:4200
referer:http://source.com:4200/
```

With "Authorization" header, OPTIONS method is automatically set:

```
:authority:www.target.com
:method:OPTIONS //<----------------This is NOT correct, caused by Authorization header
:path:/oauth2/access_token?client_id=xxx-xxx
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
access-control-request-headers:authorization
access-control-request-method:POST
origin:http://source.com:4200
referer:http://source.com:4200/
```

Because of this issue, I am unable to authorize my app, the server response is :

```
HTTP method 'OPTIONS' is not allowed. Expected 'POST'
```

So it seems that the "Authorization" header triggers the preflight in CORS.
Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because of this issue, I am unable to authorize my app, the server response is :
>
> ```
> HTTP method 'OPTIONS' is not allowed. Expected 'POST'
> ```

If you have admin access to the server the request is being sent to, then you need to configure that server to allow HTTP `OPTIONS` requests, and to respond to them with the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response headers that browsers need to see in order to allow the actual `GET` or `POST` or whatever you’re trying to make (in addition to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header browsers need to see for the actual request).

If you don’t have admin access to that server to configure it to send that CORS-enabled response to `OPTIONS` requests, then your only option for getting requests from frontend JavaScript code to work with it is to set up a CORS proxy and make the request through that. The answer at ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707) has how-to details.

Your only other option beyond that is to not make the request from your frontend JavaScript code but to instead make it from your own backend code instead, which bypasses the cross-origin restrictions that browsers impose).

> So it seems that the "Authorization" header triggers the preflight in CORS. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Yeah, when you add the `Authorization` header, that makes it no longer a “simple request”.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests explains this; it says that one of the conditions that triggers the browser to do a preflight is:

> If, apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent (for
>   example, `Connection`, `User-Agent`, or [any of the other header with
>   a name defined in the Fetch spec as a “forbidden header name”](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)),
>   the request includes any headers other than [those which the Fetch
>   spec defines as being a “CORS-safelisted request-header”](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), which
>   are the following:
>
> ```
> Accept
> Accept-Language
> Content-Language
> Content-Type
> DPR
> Downlink
> Save-Data
> Viewport-Width
> Width
> ```

The `Authorization` is not in that list, so it triggers a preflight.

Comment: I expected to somehow be able to avoid using backend server or proxy only for that initial request. All subsequent request are passing, only this one is causing issue (no I don't have access to the server, it is an API access only). Thank you anyway !